# Performance issue with Ionic 2 App

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

I want to display some items (that comes from `SqLite` **database**) in my **root** page. However when I try to retrieve those items it takes too long (something like 1 minute), **even if there's only 1 record**.

**PS:** It just happens in **root** page and **ONLY** on the first time, in other words, if I try to render that **root** page again it'll be really fast.

Here's my code:

**Service:**

```
all(): any {
    return this.storage.query('SELECT * FROM table');
}
```

**Page:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import { SomeService } from 'path/service';

export class HomePage {
    private items: Array<any>;

    constructor(private service: SomeService) {
        this.service.all().then(response => {
            this.items = response.res.rows;
        });
    }
```

Is it a known issue or what?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Observables:

**Service:**

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'`

[...]

```
all(): Observable<any> {
    let allItemsObs = Observable.create(observable => {
        observable.next(this.storage.query('SELECT * FROM table'));
    })
    return allItemsObs 
}
```

**Page:**

```
constructor(private service: SomeService) {
    this.service.all().subscribe(response => {
         this.items = response.res.rows;
    });
}
```